# Cannot run stored procedure from Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have the following code in EF Core to run a stored procedure:

```
TenandId = user.TenantId;
userName = user.UserName;
updateDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeStart = 139601;
TimeEnd = 139612;
RequestId = id;

_context.TempRequest.FromSql("EXEC dbo.AddRequest_To_TempRequest @TimeStart, @TimeEnd, @TenantId, @UpdateDate, @UserName, @RequestId",
                new SqlParameter("@TimeStart", TimeStart),
                new SqlParameter("@TimeEnd", TimeEnd),
                new SqlParameter("@TenantId", TenandId),
                new SqlParameter("@UpdateDate", updateDate),
                new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName),
                new SqlParameter("@RequestId", RequestId));
```

but when I run it, it is not working, but it is also not throwing any errors.

Am I making any mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[FromSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsql?view=efcore-2.2) is used when the raw SQL represents a *query*. And the method creates LINQ / EF Core query, but as usual with `IQueryable<>` / `IEnumerable<>` does not execute it until it is iterated (with `foreach`, `ToList()` etc.) - the so called *deferred execution*. This should explain why "*it is not working, but it is also not throwing any errors*".

For non query raw SQL statements EF Core provides another method  [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-2.2) (or `ExecuteSqlRaw` / `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` in EF Core 3.0+) which executes immediately.

Both methods can be used to call stored procedure *when executed*. Looks like the later is more appropriate for your scenario, so replacing the

```
_context.TempRequest.FromSql
```

with

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
```

should do the job.